# C++ Meaningless expression filler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, while-loop, expression, conditional-statements

I have this simple c++ program for a console application in VS 2013 Express (for Windows Desktop):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string mystr;
cout << "Welcome, what is your name? ";
getline(cin, mystr);
cout << "Nice to meet you, " << mystr << endl;
cout << "May i call you \"Idiot\" for short? (y/n)" << endl;

string mystr2;
getline(cin, mystr2);

while ( ??? ) 
{
    if (cin)
    {
        if (mystr2 == "y")
        {
            cout << "Thank you, Idiot" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (mystr2 == mystr)
            {
                cout << "You found the hidden secret! The hidden secret is..... I dunno. It is what ever you want it to be. \n \nProbably a let down." << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                if (mystr2 == "n")
                {
                    cout << "Ok then, " << mystr << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Please enter a valid response (y/n)" << endl;
                    getline(cin, mystr2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I've just started to learn and i prefer to learn as i make something, so i decided to do this. As you may guess from the final else statement, i want it to say "Please enter a valid response (y/n)" if the user has put in anything other than y, n or mystr2 == mystr. It works fine but i need to it loop so i have put it all in the while statement.

I now need an expression for the while statement which won't effect it, or is a result of the user triggering the last else statement. This filler is what i need help with.

I know it is small and pointless but i want to finish it.

Comment: I'd suggest moving both `getline` calls to become the condition.

Comment: What do you mean? @chris

Comment: Agnew fleshed it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `while(true)` for the loop to execute indefinitely. If you ever want it to stop, you must `break` or `return`

Comment: How would i go about adding the break or return?

Comment: @JoeJoe2416 you can simply call `break;` in your loop anywhere you want it to stop. It will skip whatever is after it inside of the loop and not iterate again(it will not exit the program). `Return 0;` will return in the `main` and thus exit the entire program.

Answer (score 3):

`getline` returns a reference to the stream from which it was reading. And all streams provide an implicit conversion to `bool` which results in `true` if the stream is valid (i.e. if the last operation succeeded). So it's pretty idiomatic to do this:

```
string mystr2;

while (getline(cin, mystr2))
{
    if (mystr2 == "y")
    {
        cout << "Thank you, Idiot" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (mystr2 == mystr)
        {
            cout << "You found the hidden secret! The hidden secret is..... I dunno. It is what ever you want it to be. \n \nProbably a let down." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (mystr2 == "n")
            {
                cout << "Ok then, " << mystr << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Please enter a valid response (y/n)" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `while(true)` which is just an endless loop until you `break` or `return` out of it. It will not affect your anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `while(mystr2!="y" && mystr2!="n" && mystr2!=mystr)`
That way if the input is anything other than "y", "n", or mystr, it will keep looping.